# How to add a new row to a specified table with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there a built-in method to do this?

And how to make table rows selectable and then delete a selected row?

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#yourTableId').append('<tr><td>new row</td></tr>');
```

To delete clicked row do this:

```
$('tr').click(function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: how to make table rows selectable and then delete a selected row?

Comment: I need it to happen when double clicked,is there a dblclick function?

Comment: Yes there is. `$('tr').dblclick(function () { $(this).remove(); });`

Comment: Finally,is there an attribute of tr that can pop up some hint when user focuses on that row?

Comment: What if I want to update the 1st row with new values,instead of append a new row?

Comment: The title attribute can do the hint job:)

Answer (score 1):

Just did it using this stackoverflow page:

```
$('.fw').append( 
    $('<tr/>').append( $('<td>').text('foo'))
)
```

Alternative shorthand way:

```
$('.fw').append( $('<tr><td>foo</td></tr>') );
```

Checkout http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = $('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>');
var lastRow = $('table tr:last');
row.insertAfter(lastRow);
```

Comment: What if I want to update the last row with new values,instead of append a new row?

Comment: That is an entirely different question.  You can still use "var lastRow = $('table tr:last');" to get the last row, but now you need to find the items that need updating.  Something like this might work for you: "var input = lastRow.find('input#someid').val('new value');"